# Can I tether my Macbook (Lion) to my Verizon Droid Bionic using either USB or WiFi?

Tags: tethering, verizon, motorola-droid-bionic, macos

I'm trying to use the Verizon tethering app (and have tethering enabled on my Verizon account).   My MacBook sees the hotspot, but does not connect successfully.   I'm using WPA mode.    The phone sees the Mac, but apparently never issues an IP address.

Comment: Standard question: Are other devices able to tether with your droid bionic?

Comment: I've just been going through other devices; my work Win7 laptop initially exhibited the same symptom, but I ran the connection repair wizard and it cleaned up.   I'm going to try a restart of the Mac just in case it helps.

Comment: update:  after turning wifi off and back on, it's now working.   Previously, I had switch back and forth between this and another network, but hadn't turned the adapter off completely.

Comment: Marking for close.

Comment: Feel free to post that as the answer when you can, this might help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this on the Mac by turning wifi off and then back on.   On the Win7 PC, running the network troubleshooter (which I believe turned the adapter off and on) also solved the problem.    I believe it may be related to some state left over from a previous connection in both cases.

Off-topic: with a 4G (LTE) signal, internet access was comparable (maybe better) to my 6Mb DSL access at home.